# Remove Gaps Between Items in CSS Menu

Tags: html, css

CSS:

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#nav {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    text-align:center;
    min-height:40px;
    background-color:#fafafa;
    border:1px solid #d4d4d4;
}
#nav li {
    display:inline;
}
#nav a {
    display:inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
    font-family:"Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:20px;
    color:#333;
    text-decoration:none;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
#nav li.active a, #nav li a:hover {
    color:#555;
    background-color:#e5e5e5;
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="/portfolio/">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="/archives/">Archives</a></li>
    <li><a href="/resources/">Resources</a></li>
    <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hdZNL/

I searched and found this: [CSS - <li> Items in Horizontal Menu have a Gap Between Them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3942871/css-li-items-in-horizontal-menu-have-a-gap-between-them) and it does remove the gaps but it throws everything to the left. I want the menu centred.

Comment: I would delete my answer as my method is same as the second answer in that question, I realized that after answering, so please refer to that method, it's perfect...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add empty comments between list items

```
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li><!--
--><li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
```

Here is a [sample](http://jsfiddle.net/hdZNL/5/)

Comment: Thanks this works! Now I understand what they referring to when they said "whitespace" I thought it was whitespace in the <a> element.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the post 

CSS -

Items in Horizontal Menu have a Gap Between Them

display:inline
respects the whitespace between elements and also puts them "inline".
A quick and dirty solution would be to remove whitespace between li elements.

```
<ul id="nav">
<li class="active"><a href="/">Home</a></li><li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
```

And so on.